# Nuxt.js mounted hook not firing when page redirect

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, shopify, vercel

I am implementing facebook view content event with Nuxt.js and have issue with mounted hook.
So the issue is when first page loading, mounted logged but whenever back to opened page, it isn't firing mounted hook.
This is my code.

```js
import { mapGetters, mapMutations, mapActions } from 'vuex'
export default {
  ...
  async mounted(){
    console.log('mounted')
    console.log(this.namespace)
    console.log(this.$store.state)
    if (this.$store.state[this.namespace]) {
      this.productView({ product, selectedVariant })
    }
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions('events', ['productView'])
  }
}
```

[image: console log]

As I said above, when I first load the page, I can see the log but whenever I return page, it isn't logging and page view event is also not firing.

I am using Vercel and Nuxt for Shopify headless.

Comment: Hi, how do you return on the page?

Comment: @kissu. With navigation(nuxt router) or back button neither not working.

Comment: Please give more details. As of right now, your question is lacking enough context. Consider making a [repro].